# Which are the interior points and limits of $A= \{ \frac{2^n+1}{2^n}, n \in Z^+ \}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$A= \{ \frac{2^n+1}{2^n}, n \in Z^+ \}$$

I need int(A) and limits points, but I don't know how realize it. I feel that the point limit of A is element 1. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe $\overline{A}=A\cup\{1\}$. If $x\in\overline{A}$, then every interval $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$, with $\varepsilon >0$ contains points which don't belong to $A$. Then, int$(A)=\varnothing$.